# Simple Regression Analysis by dividing the assigned data set as 30% testing and 70% training set. fit a linear regression line to the model

Tags: python, linear-regression

Please do help, I am unable to split the two. Should we do it after importing the data or before?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: Import the dataset and then programmatically using sklearn library you can split the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `train_test_split` to split your datasets.

Try this :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
```